How does Nginx add a URL prefix to the static resource files accessed by the backend service?
I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy to proxy different web sites, but unfortunately, I don't have multiple domain names. Therefore, I thought of using different URLs to distinguish between different sites. However, I encountered a problem. Below is my Nginx configuration. The purpose of this configuration is to proxy all requests starting with domain.com/gogs/ to port 6023 on the local machine. (Obviously, I am running a project named gogs on port 6023, which is similar to GitLab, but that's not what I want to discuss). With this configuration, when I visit domain.com/gogs/, the system correctly redirects to the backend service, but all requests for static js, css, etc., result in a 404. How can I solve this problem?
server {
    listen 443 ;
    server_name domain.com;
    ssl on ;
    ssl_certificate /data/certs/xxxxxxxxx.pem;  # SSL cert
    ssl_certificate_key /data/certs/xxxxxxxxx.key;  # key
    location /gogs/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6023/;
        rewrite ^/gogs/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_redirect default;
        proxy_redirect ~^/(.*)$ /gogs/$1;
        
    }
}
  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name domain.com;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


Here are the resources where I encountered a 404 error, as you can see, most of them are static resources.

Here is the docker compose file for my gogs service, it might be a little helpful.
version: "3"
services:
  gogs:
    restart: always    # 自动重启
    image: gogs/gogs
    container_name: gogs
    ports:
      - '6022:22'      # ssh 端口
      - '6023:3000'    # Web 访问端口
    volumes:
      - ./gogs-data:/data   # 数据存储


My demands are relatively simple, I hope all requests with the prefix from /gogs/ will access the corresponding backend services, including static resource requests related to this service.
